# Trouble with listening for UDP packets in python - socket.error: [Errno 24] Too many open files

Tags: python, network-programming, udp, pygame

I'm relatively new to python and I've been stuck with this issue for quite some time now.

Basically the module I am making is to be used within a game (using module pygame), however instead of receiving the keys pressed from the keyboard using the Pygame module I want to receive these keys across a network sent via UDP.

I have created a module which will listen on the defined UDP port on a separate thread, and return the key pressed to be used inside the game wherever it needs to be called.

The code I have written works for a while, however when it does its very slow and then after a while i get the following error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 164, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 399, in update
  File "/home/globe/Desktop/Asteroids/sprites.py", line 41, in update
  File "/home/globe/Desktop/Asteroids/networkControlLatest.py", line 18, in getKeyPressed
  File "/home/globe/Desktop/Asteroids/networkControlLatest.py", line 8, in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 187, in __init__
socket.error: [Errno 24] Too many open files
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 66, in apport_excepthook
ImportError: No module named fileutils

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 164, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 399, in update
  File "/home/globe/Desktop/Asteroids/sprites.py", line 41, in update
  File "/home/globe/Desktop/Asteroids/networkControlLatest.py", line 18, in getKeyPressed
  File "/home/globe/Desktop/Asteroids/networkControlLatest.py", line 8, in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 187, in __init__
socket.error: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

The networkControlLatest.py file is as follows:

```
*****from socket import *
import threading
#Class to get key pressed UDP packet on a separate thread
class networkReceive(threading.Thread):
     def __init__(self,address):
         threading.Thread.__init__(self)
     self.address = address
     self.server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
         self.server_socket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
     self.server_socket.bind(self.address)
         self.recv_data = ''

     def run(self):
         self.recv_data, addr = self.server_socket.recvfrom(2048)

def getKeyPressed():
    address = ('129.11.148.65', 6005)
    thread = networkReceive(address)
    thread.start()
    thread.join(0.01)
        recv_data = thread.recv_data
    thread.server_socket.close()
    print recv_data
    return recv_data*****
```

an example of where this is called within the game.py file is as follows:

```
keys = networkControlLatest.getKeyPressed()
        if keys == 'A':
            laser = sprites.Bullet(screen,Ship.angle,Ship.rect.center)
            bulletgroup.add (pygame.sprite.Group(laser))
            delay = 15
```

The game works fine using the keyboard so I know its some issue with the networking side of things, I just can't for the life of me work out what exactly it is! Any help would be much appreciated, I've been staring at this code for far too long..!

Comment: The error `socket.error: [Errno 24] Too many open files` hints at the fact that you forgot to close all your opened sockets. Always read the stacktraces that Python throws at you. Generally ACortes is right in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15228104/923794) that it is very expensive to open a socket for every keypress. Open it once, and just transmit your keys. Also I'd handle the keypresses locally, and only communicate e.g. position/state changes to the server. That should speed up things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a new socket for every key presed and then run a thread to get the data.
Generate the socket in a thread and write the data to a queue and then read in the getkeyPresed() from the queue.

My 2 cents.

EDIT:
As @cfi said, your problem is mainly that you never close the socket and start a new one on every call. After a number of key press the systems available File Descriptos raise to the limit and the GIL of python need do move from thread to thread and wait the number of ops set by the GIL to continue inclusive if the thread is in a I/O wait.
If you want to use threads you should understand how it works in Python and read about the improvements of GIL in python3 to manage the thread lag problem.
For your problem, You should setup a socket and prepare the thread to only receive the data.

You have a great tutorial about sockets and a easy to check example of threading at [binarytides](http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-programming-tutorial/2/)

Hope it help

Comment: Thank you very much for the input, I'm working on it now. Do you mean have the thread running constantly in the background writing data to a queue? I'm not 100% sure how to implement this as putting a while loop inside a thread doesn't seem to work, and if i call the thread more than once it will create multiple sockets.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need to do. I will get on the case, thanks for all your help

Comment: Yeah I went through that article, and it was extremely helpful. Implemented your suggestion for a queue also, thanks once again!